# Simple String Splitting SWI-Prolog Not Working

Tags: string, prolog

I'm making a database for morphological parsing in SWI-prolog and I've run into a problem. I've boiled it down now to the problem area alone.

```
lexicon('a', 'foo').
inflection('bc', 'bar').

morph(Input, Output) :-
    string_concat(First, Second, Input),
    intepretation(First, Second, Output).   

intepretation(First, Second, Output) :-
    lexicon(First, Foo),
    inflection(Second, Bar),
    string_concat(Foo, Bar, Output).
```

Basically, I give the command "morph('abc', X)" and I'm expecting the output "X = 'foobar'" but instead I get "false." The database simply splits the input string into two strings, and attempts to find rules which describe the resulting substrings. If it doesn't find any, it splits the input string again in a different location and tries again. Obviously, it should find that if it splits 'abc' into 'a' and 'bc' then the appropriate rules exist, but it doesn't.

Here is a trace:

```
   Call: (6) morph(abc, _G1441) ? creep
   Call: (7) string_concat(_G1513, _G1514, abc) ? creep
   Exit: (7) string_concat("", "abc", abc) ? creep
   Call: (7) intepretation("", "abc", _G1441) ? creep
   Call: (8) lexicon("", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lexicon("", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (7) intepretation("", "abc", _G1441) ? creep
   Redo: (7) string_concat(_G1513, _G1514, abc) ? creep
   Exit: (7) string_concat("a", "bc", abc) ? creep
   Call: (7) intepretation("a", "bc", _G1441) ? creep
   Call: (8) lexicon("a", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lexicon("a", _G1520) ? creep                    % What's happening on this line?
   Fail: (7) intepretation("a", "bc", _G1441) ? creep
   Redo: (7) string_concat(_G1513, _G1514, abc) ? creep
   Exit: (7) string_concat("ab", "c", abc) ? creep
   Call: (7) intepretation("ab", "c", _G1441) ? creep
   Call: (8) lexicon("ab", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lexicon("ab", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (7) intepretation("ab", "c", _G1441) ? creep
   Redo: (7) string_concat(_G1513, _G1514, abc) ? creep
   Exit: (7) string_concat("abc", "", abc) ? creep
   Call: (7) intepretation("abc", "", _G1441) ? creep
   Call: (8) lexicon("abc", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lexicon("abc", _G1520) ? creep
   Fail: (7) intepretation("abc", "", _G1441) ? creep
   Fail: (6) morph(abc, _G1441) ? creep
```

I'm sure this is the result of me simply misunderstanding strings or something. I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You are using SWI-specific functionality. You can do it without, too.

Comment: @false But I'm running it with SWI so it should work, right?

Comment: Try `atom_concat/3` in place of `string_concat/3`

Comment: Haha, wow. I feel like an idiot. I could have sworn I'd tried that.

Thanks.

Comment: So now your program is no longer specific to SWI!